# writing a vector to a new text file

Tags: c++, vector, text-files

Im trying to write data from my vector to a new text file, creating the new text file in the process, below is my code for doing this but im getting an error with << just after the fs, the error state no operator "<<" matches these operands

```
struct Weather
{
  int a_data;
  int b_data;
  double c_data;
  double d_data;
  double e_data;
  double ans_temp;
};


ofstream &operator << (std::ofstream &f, Weather& obj)
{
f<<obj.a_data;///Etc ...code corresponding to dispaly parameters
return f;
};

int main () 
{
  using std::vector;
  using std::string;
  using std::getline;
  using std::cout;

  vector<Weather> data_weather;
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("weatherdata.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(myfile, line)) 
    {
      if (count > 6) 
      {
            int a, b;
            double c, d, e;
            std::istringstream buffer(line); 
            std::string e_as_string;
            if (buffer >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e_as_string) 
            {
                if (e_as_string == "---")
                {
                    sun = 0.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::istringstream buffer2(e_as_string);
                    if (!(buffer2 >> sun))
                    {
                        sun = 0.0;
                    }
                }
                Weather objName = {a, b, c, d, e};
                data_weather.push_back(objName); 
            }
      }
      count++;
    }
    myfile.close();

    for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it)
    { 
        it->ans_temp = it->c_data + it->d_data /2;
    }
    for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it)
    {

        std::cout << it->ans_temp << std::endl;
    }

    std::ofstream fs("newdata.txt");
            for(vector<Weather>::const_iterator it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it) {
            fs << *it << '\n';
        }
  }
  else  

  cout << "unable to open file";

  scat::pause("\nPress <ENTER> to end the program.");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you provided an `operator<<` overload for `Weather`?

Comment: share the skeliton of Weather class. And ow u have overloaded << operator?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't overloaded << operator.

```
friend  ostream &operator << (std::ostream &f, Weather& obj)
    {
    f<<obj.a_data;  //Etc ...code corresponding to dispaly parameters
    return f;
    }
```

Comment: ok im new to this, so the above code would this be placed just before....std::ofstream fs("newdata.txt");
            for(vector<Weather>::const_iterator it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it) {
            fs << *it << '\n';

Comment: @jaylad This is a function definition. So it can't be in another function. You can put it before main after your class. And You should google for c++ operator overloading.

Comment: thanks, and i will do...ive included this function definition in the correct place before main, but i am still getting the original error i had before?

Comment: put it inside struct after members declaration

Comment: @shivakumar ive done this and i am getting an error with &operator stating too many parameters for this operator function, also the original error is still there?

Comment: @stardust_ ive done this and i am getting an error with &operator stating too many parameters for this operator function, also the original error is still there?

Comment: @jaylad Oh sorry man my bad. You can put the whole thing inside the class. I didn't notice it was `friend`. Just put it in your struct.

Comment: @stardust_ thanks i have sorted the first error, but im still getting an error with fs<< *it << .."no operator << matches these operands? could you shed any light on this cheers

Comment: @jaylad Dont forget the `using std::ofstream`

Comment: @jaylad Can you updat the question with the edits you have done?

Comment: @jaylad Try this move the operator function outside the class and remove the `friend` from it.

Comment: @stardust_ please see above code, thanks ive done that, but still keep getting the same error with...."fs << *it << '\n';" cheers

Comment: @jaylad :) You are using `const_iterator` on the loop. And the operator is declared as taking non const. Anyway change `ofstream &operator << (std::ofstream &f, Weather& obj)`  to `ofstream &operator << (std::ofstream &f, const Weather& obj)`

Comment: @stardust_ with the above code, i have done a calculation as you can see. id like to do another calculation, for example taking a selected 10 values from c_data and d_data, as apposed to the complete c_data + d_data

Comment: Remove const from friend function.

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream& operator<< (std::ofstream &f, const Weather& obj)
                                        ^^^^
{
    f<<obj.a_data;///Etc ...code corresponding to dispaly parameters
    return f;
};
```

or (not recommended)

```
for(vector<Weather>::iterator it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it) 
                    ^^^^
{
     fs << *it << '\n';
}
```